# How to silent memory leak warning in this case

Tags: objective-c

```
-(void) vCreateAddressBookAndPopulateContact
{
    self.addressBook =ABAddressBookCreate();
}
+(void) vCreateAddressBookAndPopulateContact
{
    [[RCABAddressBookHandler singleton] vCreateAddressBookAndPopulateContact];
    //[self 
}
```

The code is correct. It created an address book. The address book will be released at dealloc when the application is gone.

I do have a memory warning and I wonder what I should do?

This is how the property is declared

```
@property (nonatomic) ABAddressBookRef addressBook;
```

I release that at dealloc of course

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];
    CFRelease(_addressBook);
}
```

The warning we got is:

```
/business/Dropbox/badgers/RecentContact/RCABAddressBookHandler.m:52:1: Potential leak of an object
/business/Dropbox/badgers/RecentContact/RCABAddressBookHandler.m:51:23: Call to function 'ABAddressBookCreate' returns a Core Foundation object with a +1 retain count
/business/Dropbox/badgers/RecentContact/RCABAddressBookHandler.m:52:1: Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1
```

Comment: can you post this? ABAddressBookCreate(); Are you using ARC?

Comment: Describe in detail the memory warning you are getting. Is it a low memory warning sent to your app? a memory warning after static analysis? A memory leak detected using Instruments?

Comment: Yes I am using ARC. The memory warning I got is added:

Comment: You should use one of the `__bridge` casts instead of manually calling CFRelease, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296899/memory-leak-with-cfarray-in-arc.

Comment: @KennyTM: `ABAddressBookRef` does not have a "toll-free bridged" Foundation equivalent, as far as I know.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022019/assign-properties-arc-and-core-foundation-objects, which has a even better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the only place you set `_addressBook`, you can assign it using direct access:

```
- (void)vCreateAddressBookAndPopulateContact
{
    /* not thread safe */
    if (NULL == _addressBook) {
        _addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    }
}
```

then change the property to `readonly`.

Comment: @SeptiadiAgus in this case, because the setter has been eliminated from the equation and the static analyzer does not evaluate accesses to ivars (it cannot follow them reliably because they are potentially accessible to other parts of the program in the meantime). if the case were not so simple, then you would instead implement a setter, then write `- (void)vCreateAddressBookAndPopulateContact { AddressBookRef ab = ABAddressBookCreate(); \n self.addressBook = ab; \n CFRelease(ab); } `. personally, i favor assigning these ivars which do not change in the initializer (where possible).